# Upload image use Ckeditor and KCFinder

Tags: upload, ckeditor, kcfinder

I want to upload image use Ckeditor, I use KCfinder.
I imported success, but when i click button Browse Server, empty dialog appears. I use centos on vagrant

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Demo CKEditor</title>
   <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Demo CKEditor</h1>
   <form >
      <textarea name="ck" id="ck"></textarea>
      <script>CKEDITOR.replace('ck');</script>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Config.js:

```
config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
```

[empty dialog appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Pdn.png)

[tree forder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8ZHk.png)

Comment: Bạn đặt câu hỏi kiểu này mà ko post code của bạn lên thì ko ai hiểu nổi: sorry I has been using Vietnamese

Comment: Probably you have problem with php or\and file permissions. Is displaying of php errors is turned on ?

Comment: @HồngVănVít Mình đã post ảnh lên rồi mà bạn. code có gì đâu, chỉ là tải cái file ckeditor và kcfinder về thôi mà, mình đã cấu hình thành công cả 2 cái và nó có hiện button upload ảnh đó thôi. Nhưng khi ấn vào thì nó không hiện ra trình quản lý upload của kcfinder??

Comment: @SAZ "Is displaying of php errors is turned on", I don't know. please help me!!